# How to open Modal with item information when clicking a FlatList element?

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog

What I am trying to achieve is to open a modal dialog when the user press on one of the items of a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) component. The code of this list looks like this:

```
class MyItem extends React.Component { 
  _onPress = () => { 
    this.props.onPressItem(this.props.item); 
  }; 
  render() { 
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
            {...this.props}
            onPress={this._onPress}
            >
            <Text style={styles.itemText}> {this.props.item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ) 
  } 
}

export default class MyList extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}, // some data correctly loaded
            isModalVisible: false
        };
    };

    _onPressItem = (item) => { 
        this._showModal;
    };

    _showModal = () => this.setState({ isModalVisible: true })

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <MyItem 
            style={styles.row}
            item={item}
            onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
        />
    );

    render() {
      return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Tittle</Text>
          </View>
          <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
              <FlatList 
                  data={this.state.data}
                  ItemSeparatorComponent = {this._flatListItemSeparator}
                  renderItem={this._renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
              />
          </ScrollView>
          <MyModal modalVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}/>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
    }
}
```

Styles, FlatList data and some functions have been removed because they are not relevant for this issue.

As you can see, `MyModal` component is declared after `ScrollView` component. The code is based on the use of react-native [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) component:

```
export default class MyModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isModalVisible: props.modalVisible
    };
  };

  _setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={false}
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                        <Text>Item Detail</Text>
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            style={styles.buttonContainer}
                            onPress={() => { this._setModalVisible(false) }}>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Close</Text> 
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  innerContainer: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#34495e',
 },
 buttonContainer: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
    borderRadius: 15
 },
 buttonText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#ecf0f1',
    fontWeight: '700'
 },
});
```

Current behaviour is `MyModal` component being displayed when I access to `MyList` component for the first time, I can close it and then the `FlatList` is there but when a list item is pressed, `MyModal` component is not displayed.

**How can I manage to hide Modal and open it only when a list item is pressed?**

Another doubt related to this is:

**How to pass the pressed item object to `MyModal` component?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first part may just be a typo - in `MyList._onPressItem` you're not actually calling `_showModal` (missing the brackets).

Comment: One other quick tip - `FlatList` is a scrolling view in itself - there's no need to wrap it in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thank you so much I removed the ScrollView and it works perfect, I am stuck trying to access the selectedItem in MyModal component, as I wrote in the comment to your answer, any sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Passing the `item` through to the modal

To pass the selected item to your modal, you'll need to add it as a `prop` on your `Modal` component.

You can remember the selected item in `MyList`'s state:

```
_onPressItem = (item) => { 
    this._showModal(item);
};

_showModal = (selectedItem) => this.setState({ isModalVisible: true, selectedItem })
```

And then pass it through to the modal when you `render` it from `MyList`:

```
// ...
      </ScrollView>
      <MyModal 
        modalVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} 
        selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem} />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
// ...
```

## Controlling the modal's visibility

Currently you have a modal visibility boolean in both `MyList`'s state (`isModalVisible`, which is passed through to `MyModal` as the `modalVisible` prop) and also in `MyModal`'s state (`modalVisible`). There's no need for the last one - it'll just give you a headache trying to keep them in sync. Just use the props to "[control](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)" `MyModal`, keeping a single source of truth, and pass a callback to allow `MyModal` to tell `MyList` that the modal should be dismissed.

```
// ...
      </ScrollView>
      <MyModal 
        modalVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} 
        selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}
        onDismiss={this._hideModal} />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
// ...
```

A new stateless `MyModal`:

```
export default class MyModal extends Component {    
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={false}
            visible={this.props.modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => { this.props.onDismiss() }}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                        <Text>Item Detail</Text>
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            style={styles.buttonContainer}
                            onPress={() => { this.props.onDismiss() }}>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Close</Text> 
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The modal visibility works nice! I also removed the containing View of MyModal. The problem persists passing the selected item to the Modal, I'm getting error "null is not an object (evaluating "this.props.selectedItem.name")" caused by adding <Text>{this.props.selectedItem.name}</Text> in MyModal component and invoking it with prop selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}

Comment: @juankysmith - could that be because `selectedItem` is initially undefined? The `Modal` will be rendered "off screen" (virtually) as soon as `MyList` mounts, so it'll need to be prepared for whatever `props` you have ready at that point (even if not visible - unless you go with @ShubhnikSingh's method discussed below). If not that, I'd need to see your updated code ( https://snack.expo.io/ is handy)

Comment: I used your _showModal and _onPressItem functions, added selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem} to MyModal invokation inside MyList and added this.state = {
            ...
            selectedItem: null
        }; to the MyList constructor.

When I access to the prop "selectedItem" in MyModal component, it is null

Comment: Yes, it'll be `null` until you select an item. I'd wrap whatever needs `selectedItem` in `{ this.props.selectedItem && <Foo>{ /* use selectedItem here */</Foo> }` (inside `MyModal`'s `render()`), or go with @ShubhnikSingh's method and guard the whole `<MyModal>` the same way inside `MyList`'s `render()`. Not much difference in your case.

Comment: Inside the `render()` method of `MyList`, just replace `<MyModal ... />` with `{ this.state.selectedItem && <MyModal ... />}`. That works by shortcutting out of mounting `MyModal` if `selectedItem` is falsey, and evaluates to `null`, which gets left out of the component hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyItem extends React.Component { 
  _onPress = () => { 
    this.props.onPressItem(this.props.item); 
  }; 
  render() { 
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
            {...this.props}
            onPress={this._onPress}
            >
            <Text style={styles.itemText}> {this.props.item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ) 
  } 
}

export default class MyList extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}, // some data correctly loaded
            isModalVisible: false,
            selectedItem: null
        };
    };

    _onPressItem = (item) => { 
        this._showModal(item);
    };

    _hideMyModal = () => {
        this.setState({isModalVisible: false})
    }

    _showModal = (item) => this.setState({ isModalVisible: true, 
    selectedItem: item })

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <MyItem 
            style={styles.row}
            item={item}
            onPressItem={() => this._onPressItem(item)}
        />
    );

    render() {
      return(
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Tittle</Text>
          </View>
          <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
              <FlatList 
                  data={this.state.data}
                  ItemSeparatorComponent = {this._flatListItemSeparator}
                  renderItem={this._renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
              />
          </ScrollView>
          { this.state.isModalVisible && <MyModal selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem} modalVisible={this.state.isModalVisible} hideModal={this_hideMyModal} /> }
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      );
    }
}
```

When you press the item in FlatList, just set it in the state and pass it as a prop to MyModal component(pretty self explanatory).

```
export default class MyModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isModalVisible: props.modalVisible
    };
  };

  _setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={false}
            visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                        <Text>Item Detail</Text>
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            style={styles.buttonContainer}
                            onPress={() => { this.props.hideModal() }}>
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Close</Text> 
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In your previous code in `MyModal` you were doing this --> `onPress={() => { this._setModalVisible(false) }}>` which will hide the modal in the `MyModal` class but `MyModal` is still rendered in the `MyList` class. So you might be unable to click the FlatList item again. I passed a prop `hideModal` which will remove the `MyModal` component from the `MyList`. In my revised code you don't need to pass `modalVisible` prop also, but its up to you for that.

Comment: This is a good answer and prompted me to add the "Controlling visibility" section to my answer. I worried that the use of `{ this.state.isModalVisible && <MyModal ... />}` would disrupt the dismiss animation but actually having tried it it works just fine. The biggest difference is that this will cause the modal and all its contents to be unmounted/remounted, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @RobHogan ,Thanks for discussing :) but If I have to avoid`{ this.state.isModalVisible && <MyModal ... />}` this thing than i think from your answer we have to remove the root `<View>` from `MyModal`, isn't it?

Comment: I can't see any need for the containing `<View>` but I don't think it does any harm -  it never has any dimensions because `<Modal>` is positioned absolutely (and `Modal` actually fronts a native subview, which is why the dismiss animation works even if you immediately stop rendering it). If the `View` was a problem for touch events, you could allow them to pass through it by setting its `pointerEvents` prop to `none`/`box-none`.

Comment: Thanks! The modal visibility works nice! I also removed the containing View of MyModal. The problem persists passing the selected item to the Modal, I'm getting error "null is not an object (evaluating "this.props.selectedItem.name")" caused by adding <Text>{this.props.selectedItem.name}</Text> in MyModal component and invoking it with prop selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}

Comment: @RobHogan just out of curiosity, how do you measure react-native performance?, so that I can check the performance hits. Thanks for the insights though :)

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh - personally, in a very ad-hoc way, depending on the kind of thing I'm testing. I haven't come across a really satisfactory way of profiling in general, largely because you only get realistic results in release builds. The RN perf monitor and xcode profiler (for CPU/RAM/frame rate), react native debugger (optimising component hierarchy, impact of prop changes), and just the standard "repeat n times and time it" are my usual tools. No surprises I'm afraid! In cases like this it depends a lot on use case (what's in the modal, how much of it changes, how often it's invoked, etc)

Comment: @RobHogan If you don't mind can you please shed some light on these two measure you mentioned ---> **react native debugger (optimising component hierarchy, impact of prop changes), and just the standard "repeat n times and time it" are my usual tools.**

1) I mean how do you do optimising component hierarchy, measure impact of prop changes?

2) and what about "repeat n times and time it" ?
Thanks

Comment: @juankysmith If you render the <MyModal /> component only when you setState for `isModalVisible: true` than I don't think it should be the case.

Comment: @ShubhnikSingh "measure" was a strong word for me to use ;). https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger will let you clearly see the full component hierarchy so you can visually spot deep sections that could maybe be slimmed down or unmounted. Nodes get briefly highlighted in yellow when a prop changes, so you can spot things that might be getting re-rendered unnecessarily. It's not a magic bullet but I find it handy.